# Update table with data from table in a separate database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

```
TableA 
ID Address Location Country
1   NULL     Region1  Austrailia
2   NULL     Region2  Antartica
3   NULL    Region3   Egypt

TableB
ID  Address        Name
1   test avenue    james
2   test avenue 2  jessica
3   test avenue 3  joshua
```

I am working on a query to migrate data Address data from Database 1, TableB to Database 2 TableA. So far I have tried to do the query below however that only inserts one record for the entire database, I want to insert each new sequential address into TableA as it appears in TableB.

```
UPDATE [dbo].[TableA]
SET [dbo].[TableA].[Address]= Table2.ID
FROM (SELECT [TableB].[ID]
        FROM [TableB]) AS Table2
WHERE [dbo].[TableA].[ID] <= 1449
```

This results in all records only having the first ID which is 1, so all the rows in TableA are Address = 1, instead of 1,2,3 etc. I think I am close but not quite sure what I am missing

**Desired Result**

```
TableA 
    ID Address Location Country
    1   1        Region1  Austrailia
    2   2        Region2  Antartica
    3   3        Region3   Egypt
```

Comment: Do you mean, for each ID on table A add all addresses of table B? Or TableA.ID = TableB.ID?

Comment: @McNets For each ID of TableB, add TableB.ID into TableA.Address

Comment: Please, could you add the desired result of your sample data?

Comment: @McNets edited question with desired result, so populate TableA with the ID's of TableB

Comment: Are you sure updating `ID` is a good idea?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
UPDATE a
SET a.Address = b.ID
FROM TableA a
JOIN TableB b ON b.ID = a.ID
WHERE a.ID <= 1449
```

Comment: I tried this, sadly it has no effect on the data in the column I want to update.

Comment: Not sure if the JOIN is what is causing the problem being that both tables have nothing really to join on, perhaps

Comment: If there's nothing to join on, how do you know which row is assigned to which row on the other table?

Comment: Based on your sample data, my code will work fine.

Comment: Well the ID's that I want to copy over are sequential, so for example 1,2,3,4,5.... etc. I just want to use the numbers that exists in TableB to populate the Address column in tableA

Comment: Then my statement should work.